# Storing vertex in a priority queue base on the weight of edges (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, priority-queue, vertex

I am having a difficult time trying to implement my code. So basically I created a class called vertex, each vertex then points to other vertices creating a graph and an adjacency list, to implement this I created a struct inside my class Vertex called Edge. Each edge has a weight and a Vertex to which it is pointing to. Heres my code to give you a better understanding.

```
Vertex {
public:
    void setPQ() {
    for( int i = 0; i < adjList.size(); ++i) {
        pq.push( adjList[i].node );
    }
}
private:
    struct Edge {
        Vertex* node; // The vertex the edge is pointing to
        int thatVertex;
        float weight;

        Egde( ) {
            thatVertex = 0;
            weight = 0;
        }
        bool operator<( const Edge & rhs) {
            return this.weight < rhs.weight;
        }
    };

    vector< Edge > adjList;
    int thisVertex;
    int dist;
    bool known = false;
    piority_queue< Vertex*, vector<Vertex*>, Edge > pq;
};
```

I'm implementing Dijkstra algorithm so thats why I have known and dist and other stuff. What I want to do is in each Vertex (or node) have a priority queue and in that queue, I want to store all vertices that `this` is pointing to. In other words, I want to store all vertices that are adjacent to `this` vertex and sort it using the weight of an Edge. How am I suppose to do this? I need to compare the weight of an edge and then store the Vertex of what that Edge contains. I have no idea how to do this and I don't even think my implementation is correct. Can someone help me and explain how am I suppose to do this?

Thank you

Comment: can you just use a priority_queue of `Edge`'s? You pretty much have that already.  `priority_queue<Edge> pq;`  after that, make your `Edge::operator<` const and it would work.  If you dont want to do that, you'd need to define some sort of comparator class, I think.

Comment: @dwcanillas I can't, I need to access the Vertex that has the least amount of weight going to it. What's a comparator class?

Comment: You still would be able to do that, `pq.top().node`

Comment: or do you want to sort by the total weight going to each vertex?  If that is the case, why are you making a priority queue in the vertex class itself?

Comment: @dwcanillas, I need to do it as an assignment, its a requirement that I use a priority queue to access the vertex that has the minimum edge going to it. And I feel soooooooo stupid. I'm sorry sometimes when I'm stuck on something for so long I fail to see the obvious answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue gives you pseudo-code for Dijkstra's algorithm, showing you how to associate a priority with a vertex - it is the minimum cost path to that vertex found so far.